# Using cmd in VB, using commands and receiving output

Tags: vb.net, cmd, output

I need to know, if you could help me, how to insert commands in vb then they run in cmd and i get the output.

I need to do "net localgroup Administradores a58465 /add" and get the error message if there is one.

Solution:  `Dim myProcess As Process = New Process
        Dim s As String
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe"
        myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
        myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
        myProcess.Start()

```
    Dim sIn As System.IO.StreamWriter = myProcess.StandardInput
    Dim sOut As System.IO.StreamReader = myProcess.StandardOutput
    Dim sErr As System.IO.StreamReader = myProcess.StandardError

    'sIn.AutoFlush = True
    sIn.Write("cls" & System.Environment.NewLine)
    sIn.Write("net user" & System.Environment.NewLine)
    sIn.Write("exit" & System.Environment.NewLine)
    s = sOut.ReadToEnd()

    If Not myProcess.HasExited Then
        myProcess.Kill()
    End If
    LB1.Text = s
    LB1.Visible = True
    sIn.Close()
    sOut.Close()
    sErr.Close()
    myProcess.Close()`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Process.Start. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb(v=vs.110).aspx

Also look for the ProcessStartInfo class, which will give you options on how to kick off an external process.

Console input and output can be made available to your program through ProcessStartInfo.

Comment: That lets me call other programs, how do i write code?

Comment: Did you read through the documentation of the link I sent along with ProcessStartInfo? Take a look at this example. http://www.dotnetperls.com/redirectstandardoutput

Comment: I did read it and it didnt help. I did (kind of) understand it but maybe i am just not as experienced as i have to be to come up with the code.
But i did find some help in another post.
For those who want a simple way to get putting code in cmd ill post it in the question. Thank you anyway. If you think i should change something in the code let me know.